# Button to insert tags to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I believe this has been answered before but how can I have buttons / images / whatever so that when I click them it inserts the `<b></b>` around the cursor position like what you find in forums (and even the StackOverflow ask a question page)?
Again, I know this has been answered but all I could find was using jQuery and my server does not support it...
Thanks

Comment: just out of interest: how does your sever not allow jQuery?

Comment: jQuery doesn't run on your server, it runs on your PAGE.

Comment: jQuery is client side.  Your server doesn't need to support it.  The user's browser will do that.

Comment: what's your point? flaming someone that is not willing to include jquery? or at least "cant"

probably he is working for a company that do not want to include external libraries ;) he asked for a plain-vanilla js solution ;)

Comment: i did not intend to flame. I know there are legitimate reasons why people can't use a framework and I was curious.

Comment: Good point about running on a page, though every time I have tried jQuery it hasn't ended well so vanilla is good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one I wrote awhile ago [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXnru/)

```
    function boldText(textAreaId, link) 
    {
        var browser=navigator.appName
        var b_version=navigator.appVersion

        if (browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer" && b_version>='4')
        {
            var str = document.selection.createRange().text;
            document.getElementById(textAreaId).focus();
            var sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = "<b>" + str + "</b>";
            return;
        }

        field = document.getElementById(textAreaId);
        startPos = field.selectionStart;
        endPos = field.selectionEnd;
        before = field.value.substr(0, startPos);
        selected = field.value.substr(field.selectionStart, (field.selectionEnd - field.selectionStart));
        after = field.value.substr(field.selectionEnd, (field.value.length - field.selectionEnd));
        field.value = before + "<b>" + selected + "</b>" + after;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

see what alex king's approach is:
http://alexking.org/blog/2003/06/02/inserting-at-the-cursor-using-javascript